# Using Chartist on Sails.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, chartist.js

I'm trying to use Chartist with sails.js and i'm getting an error that says

> Chartist is not defined]

The code I'm running is

```html
<%new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  series: [
    [5, 9, 7, 8, 5, 3, 5, 4]
  ]
}, {
  low: 0,
  showArea: true
});
%>
```

I don't know why this is happening but i already installed Chartist via the command

> npm install Chartist

Thank you for your time and i hope i get some answers soon.

Comment: For aditional info, here's the link for the chartist.js website
[link](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access npm installed module in the browser. You can do that by following this article.

> http://dontkry.com/posts/code/using-npm-on-the-client-side.html

I'd rather go for either bower or cdn instead npm.

Bower :

> bower install chartist --save

CDN :

> `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
>   <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Tried to install bower so that i could install the chartist using bower....it gave me several errors :c
I'm Trying the CDN Method now
@Pavan Bhushan Maganti tried this code:
`code` <div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" id="chart1"></div>
<div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" id="chart2"></div>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js">
/* code from getting started [link]https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html  */ 
</script>
And it didnt work...i get a blank place